# How to set absolute (not %) position for the center of a shape drawable gradient?

Tags: android, android-layout, shapedrawable

I've got a shape drawable with a radial gradient inside it.  The shape is a rectangle, and I'm trying to position the center of the radial gradient near the bottom right corner.  I can get it in the general vicinity using the centerX and centerY attributes set to values like 0.98, but I'm dealing with rectangles of different heights (same width), so the taller the rectangle is, the higher the center position is, relative to the bottom right corner.

It seems I can only position the center as a percentage of the view width/height, contrary to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#attr_android%3acenterX).  That is, even without the "%" in the value, it is treated as a percentage.

What I'd like to do is somehow say "put the center 5dp up and to the left of the bottom right corner".  Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You might try use a [`Layer-List`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList), there you can specify margins of overlaying layer items, which can be drawables.

Comment: As it happens, my shape IS inside a layer-list, but my issue is positioning the radial gradient's center within a particular shape item in the list, not relative to other shapes in the list.  Perhaps I'm not quite understanding your suggestion.